# Getting started with Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am getting started with exacttarget. Having a fair bit of experience in salesforce, I find exacttarget to be completely different. I am required to do a POC on mobile connect. Having gone through the documentation, it seems the first thing is to configure short code into the account. The org that I have been given  is a production environment wherein a separate business unit has been created.

I have the following questions to start with:

1. Is the business unit a separate environment altogether and can this business unit be considered as a sandbox in itself.
2. How can i know if short code is set up in the marketing cloud, or specifically the BU.
3. How do i create records , especially contact records. While trying to save a contact by clicking on Add Contacts in the mobile connect page, i am unable to save the data.

Appreciate any help in this regard.